# scope variable in ng-include and ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with my scope variables.
Actually, I do have an index.html file where we can find a navbar added with a ng-include :

```
<div class=col-xs-9 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation ng-include="'views/common/navside.html'"></div>
```

And just after I have my ng-view :

```
<div class="col-xs-12 content" ng-view=""></div>
```

Here is my problem : 
In my navbar, I show if I am logged or not, and when I log myself, the view changes with a $location.path, and I initialize a $scope.$parent variable with the login of the user.
If I refresh the page, I get the $scope.$parent variable in the navbar, but if I don't, I get nothing and I still have my "Log in" choice

My navside.html page search the right variable as I'm doing this :

```
<div ng-if="$parent.login.length > 0"> ... </div>
<div ng-if="$parent.login.length == 0"> ... </div>
```

Is there any way to be able to have a scope variable which is common to the ng-include and ng-view?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is simple: use $rootScope.$broadcast('Login'); when you login.

And in the navbar Ctrl:

```
$rootScope.$on('Login', function () {
   // set the $scope.$parent variable
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll try this and keep you in touch! Thanks

Comment: WORKED ! Thank you !

So to give more details for the future peoples who will come here, in my login controller :

$rootScope.$broadcast('login', loginVariable);

In my nav controller :

$rootScope.$on('login',function(event, data) {
            $scope.$parent.login= data;
});